# Convert matrix table into single row in Excel (no VBA)

Tags: excel

In Excel, my Data looks like this

```
A  B  C  D

15 16 17 18
11 12 13 14
7  8  9  10
```

I am looking for a solution (without VBA) to transform my data into a single row, like this:

`15 16 17 18 11 12 13 14 7 8 9 10`

Comment: Does the range ever contain duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have access to the `TOROW` function:

`=TOROW(A1:D3)`

Comment: Best solution for me (as it works under macOS), need to join the Beta Channel to get to this function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
=OFFSET(Matrix,MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$7)),ROWS(Matrix)),TRUNC((COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$7))/(ROWS(Matrix))),1,1)
```

Comment: No working; I guess I need to replace Matrix with my table range? But this not working either; I am getting #REF error ... I'm investigating ...

Comment: it is only printing the first row of my matrix; my formula (need to change , to ; because of my system preferences):
`=OFFSET(A1:D3;MOD((COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$7));ROWS(A1:D3));TRUNC((COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$7))/(ROWS(A1:D3)));1,1)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have `TEXTJOIN()` then try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A1:D3)&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: For both answers I am fighting with language translations of formulas; do you know by any chance a good way to convert function translations from english into another language?

Comment: I am missing the function FILTERXML ... yet I am on the latest Excel for macOS (Office 365, 16.60) ...

Comment: FILTERXML is only available for Windows machines. > The FILTERXML function is not available in Excel for the web and Excel for Mac. see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7